# AlertDialog default size

Tags: android

I have an AlertDialog that automatically resizes itself according to its content (for now, a simple text message). Is there any way to set a default size for the dialog without creating a custom layout?

If this is not possible, how would I go about making the custom layout? All I need it to do is set a default size for the dialog, say 400 by 300 px.

Also, sorry if this is a lot, but how would I implement the custom layout in my code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: fixed size is maybe not the best idea, but using pixels is really the worst ;- if that is feasible, use dp and not px as unit! 400*300px is the equivalent of 2 screens on a old low res smartphone and a few centimeters on a new HD phone. Be carefull.

Comment: See, you've already caught one of my mistakes. Thanks for pointing that out, I will be sure to keep it in mind.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the AlertDialog.Builder setView method: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(android.view.View)

You can just make a custom xml layout and set the layout_width and layout_height attributes to whatever DP(preferrable to PX) you wish. Then you just use a LayoutInflater to inflate that view and set it as the dialog view. You can even have a TextView in the view and set the text there or just use the dialog setMessage or setTitle methods.